# Multiple database connection in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've faced a trouble while implementing multiple database connections in a Rails 4 application. Along with the primary database connection I've created secondary connection by specifying details in `database.yml`.

```
secondary_base:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 host: localhost
 database: secondary_db
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: postgres
```

Then created a model named `SecondaryBase` which holds the connection to that secondary database. Code given below:

**secondary_base.rb**

```
class SecondaryBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "secondary_base"
end
```

Then added two models `Member` and `Subdomain`.

**member.rb**

```
class Member < SecondaryBase
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subdomains
end
```

**subdomain.rb**

```
class Subdomain < SecondaryBase
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members
end
```

Now as you can see that `Member` and `Subdomain` models are related by `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. So when I'm trying to insert data to the join table named `members_subdomains`, It's now working and giving me the error something like that `PG: Undefined table`, though the table exits in `secondary_db` database. What I understood that rails is trying to find the `members_subdomains` table in primary database.But when I tried the same code in Rails 3.2.13, then there were no problem at all, everything is fine. Have any of you deal with a similar problem before? Please help.

Comment: afaict, this appears to be a breaking change in Rails 4.1. I've just upgraded an application with this scenario and encountered the same problem. is there an issue on rails github that you know of?

Comment: @MikeCampbell I didn't found any helpful resources on github or other sites that time.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will need to switch from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many :through` to get this to work.  In order to do that, just create a model for the join table - I'll call it `MemberSubdomain'.

```
class SecondaryBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "secondary_base"
end

class MemberSubdomain < SecondaryBase
  self.table_name = 'members_subdomains'
end

class Member < SecondaryBase
  has_many :member_subdomains
  has_many :subdomains, :through => :member_subdomains, :source => :subdomain
end

class Subdomain < SecondaryBase
  has_many :member_subdomains
  has_many :members, :through => :member_subdomains, :source => :member
end
```

Comment: Then what is the actually the problem with `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: The problem is that it's not associated with a model so there is no way to tell it which database to connect to.